# can't assign command/var

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make this code delete a row from this table, but i get these errors. If I remove my $action tag. then $IDnum causes an error. Sorry for the dumb question, still learning php =}

```
if ($action == "deletead") {  // remove AD
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ads where ID = '$IDnum'") or die(mysql_error());
    $i=$i++;
}

    $letknown = "<b>User account removed</b><br>";

    echo "<div class=\"adcode\"><b>$ID : $adname</b><br /><a href=\"?action=deletead&IDnum=$ID\">Delete Ad</a><br /><br />$adcode</div><br />\n";
    echo "<br /><hr />";
```

Notice: Undefined variable: action in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\adgate\displayads.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: IDnum in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\adgate\displayads.php on line 39

Comment: where you set $action variable?

Comment: From where script receive variables `$action` and `$IDnum`?

Comment: The PHP notice is quite straightforward. `Undefined variable: action`, means you used `action` for something but it has nothing assigned to it yet. same thing for `Undefined variable: IDnum`.

Comment: yep and thanks. i see and understand it better now. I was passing IDNUM on the fly. so '$_GET[IDnum] worked better , thanks to the guys below refreshing my memory/knowledge. in the learning process

Comment: how you are sending values. IN url or through POST ?

Comment: echo "<b>$ID : $adname</b><br /><a href=\"?action=deletead&IDnum=$ID\">Delete Ad</a><br /><br />\n";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code your structure properly like this and use $_GET['action'] for getting url parameter

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "deletead") {  // remove AD
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ads where ID = '$_GET[IDnum]'") or die(mysql_error());
$i=$i++;
}

$letknown = "<b>User account removed</b><br>";

echo "<div class=\"adcode\"><b>$ID : $adname</b><br /><a href=\"?action=deletead&IDnum=$ID\">Delete Ad</a><br /><br />$adcode</div><br />\n";
echo "<br /><hr />";
```

Comment: thanks for the code example/working example. helped me see the issue and solution better

Answer (score 2):

Try to get echo $action and $IDnum and see what value you are getting.

I think $action and $IDnum is not getting any value that is why only this notice comes.

Comment: have u got solution or still looking for ? can i give u any other sugggestion ?

Comment: I got it, but i am still getting 
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\adgate\displayads.php on line 49

code donated by LearneR and Yogesh Suthar (thanks guys for the help)
line 49 : if ($_GET['action'] == "deletead") {  // remove AD

I'm looking into how to assign this action index/var, it is passed via the delete link. First time missing with links passing info via php. should of used a button and I wouldn't have this error.

It works fine, but I have php errors turned on so i can see them.

Comment: going back to my php books and php.net to try to figure this out. i HATE ERRORS!! =}

Comment: u still searching for solution ?

Comment: yeppers. need to assign a value soemhow without messing it up when the link sends it

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this, You did not get the value of variable passing through url

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "deletead") {  // remove AD
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ads where ID = $_GET['IDnum']") or die(mysql_error());
    $i=$i++;
}

    $letknown = "<b>User account removed</b><br>";

    echo "<div class=\"adcode\"><b>$ID : $adname</b><br /><a href=\"?action=deletead&IDnum=$ID\">Delete Ad</a><br /><br />$adcode</div><br />\n";
    echo "<br /><hr />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs because you are not getting the values, which are passed in that href.
try this,YOu should use
   `$IDnum = $_REQUEST['IDnum']` 
Same for action 
    `$action = $_REQUEST['action']`